I am creating a video player app as per the my course instruction but i get stuck on the code
I am getting an error in the URI import part, along with parsing for binding.
tried AI but it is not giving relevant result , this video player play the video from the res folder. error image
package com.example.video_player

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.MediaController
import android.widget.VideoView
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        // Find the VideoView class by its id
        val videoView = findViewById<VideoView>(binding.testView.id)
        // Creating MediaController
        val mediaController = MediaController(this)
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView)
        // specify the location of media file
        val uri: Uri = parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/raw/test")
        // Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
        videoView.requestFocus()
        videoView.start()
    }
}


There is few issue in your code specifically with the import of Uri and the usage of binding for findViewById
Add this to your imports: this is for URI
import android.net.Uri

You're using binding.testView.id, but it seems you're not using ViewBinding or DataBinding in your current layout.
ou should use findViewById directly with the correct resource ID (R.id.testView)
Also Correct your URI parse code also here :
val uri: Uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/raw/test")

Here's the corrected version of your code
package com.example.video_player

import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.MediaController
import android.widget.VideoView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        // Adjust window insets if needed
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }

        // Find the VideoView by its id
        val videoView = findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.testView)

        // Create and set MediaController for videoView
        val mediaController = MediaController(this)
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView)

        // Specify the location of the media file (video in res/raw folder)
        val uri: Uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/raw/test")

        // Set the MediaController and URI, then start the videoView
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
        videoView.requestFocus()
        videoView.start()
    }
}


It is working now ? If you get help from this can you up vote the answer so others can find useful in the future !

yes it is working now, i tried to upvote it but it is saying
Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.
